# sequential circuit chaser light

Tags: simulation, clock, flipflop, latch

I am trying to implement a sequential circuit in logisim that has LED chaser lights (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo8Qls0HnWo) like on this car. I have tried using D flip flops with a clock and connecting them together and to no avail. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a Larson Scanner and there are many ways to do.

Personally, I think easiest way is to use a cheap (less than $3) micro-controller like a PIC or AVR and a bit of software. Search for "minimal larson scanner" on google for some designs.

You could overkill and use an Ardunio-based board. This makes your work a little easier, but costs a little more. Here is a project I did a few years ago that can do Larson Scanner and several other programmable patterns...

http://josh.com/ALSO/

If you really want to solve the problem with discrete logic, here is an example design, but you can see it is more complex and lots more parts than the micro-controller solutions...

http://hackaday.com/2011/04/20/larson-scanner-using-7400-series-logic-hardware/

Comment: The "flashlight effect" on your ALSO project is pretty awesome.

Comment: To use a cheap... what? I think your prhase got truncated. I'd upvote it if I hadn't made me so curious.

Comment: :) fixed. Apparently Stack Exchange chokes on an open parenthesis followed by a less than sign.